# Sharepoint online GraphAPI create list with invalid request

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create a list with in a site using the graph API.

URL: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenantsharepoint.com}:/sites/{siteName}:/lists](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Btenantsharepoint.com%7D:/sites/%7BsiteName%7D:/lists)

Request Body:

```
{
  "displayName": "Books",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Author",
      "text": { }
    },
    {
      "name": "PageCount",
      "number": { }
    }
  ],
  "list": {
    "template": "genericList"
  }
}
```

It was working fine but all of sudden it started giving me below exception:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Provided identifier is malformed - site collection id is not valid",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-31T05:28:46",
      "request-id": "302c5ee3-3799-4a24-a2a3-185d7801f78a"
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers leads would be appreciated.

Comment: When I tried with site UUID it is working.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site UUID}/lists

Comment: This is expected behavior. As per documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create

This is the graph call to create list :
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists

Comment: Thank you @AbhijeetJadhav, I understand that, but earlier it was working without any issue during my development.